# Editing my question and getting fresh answers

Tags: discussion

There's a bit a problem I face on this site, and it might well be my lack of understanding on how this site works. If this is the case, I would appreciate someone correcting me on how things work.

Okay, so. I have a question that I really want answering. I write my question and post it. It's a programming question so exactly how technical to get can sometimes be the trick. Sometimes I get it right, sometimes I get it wrong. Let's say I got it wrong and two of the answers are requests for more information. At this point, I find myself faced with a problem. Do I a) edit my question or b) post a new question with the new information?

I'm sure you're thinking 'a' since it represents the best behaviour. Even so, a newly asked question has momentum. It's more likely to get attention and therefore answers because it's so much more visible. An edited question remains where it was. I can't contact users to say that I updated my question and asking them kindly to review it with the new information supplied.

It's a bit of a problem I've faced here. How does an edited question get any attention?

Comment: "I can't contact users to say that I updated my question ", you certainly can. If they have posted a comment just use "@<username>" and let them know you've edited.

Comment: Edited questions have the same momentum you are probably just not used to switching to the __active__ tab where the list is sorted by latest edits

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, if you get requests for more information, you should edit that information into the question, not ask a new question (the assumption being that the question remains essentially the same question, only with more detail).

> How does an edited question get any attention?

Edits bump the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you keep asking the same question over and over people will realize this, close your question as a duplicate, and likely end up giving you some downvotes.  This is likely to result in you being question banned, so it's not a terribly productive solution.

If you have additional information to add to your question you should be editing it into the question itself.

---

There are a number of different possible views that people use to search for questions.  Some of them are based on a questions activity, which is the last time the question or an answer to it was posted, the last time a post was edited, when a bounty was last added, etc.  Editing a post will bring it to the top of such views.

The homepage also incorporates recent activity into its algorithm, but it also incorporates other variables, so edits may or may not result in additional homepage attention.

Users using entirely different views, such as the list of questions by their posted date, will be unaffected by edits to questions.